# Get dropdown selected value and redirect that page on button click

Tags: php, jquery

i have a dropdown menu and a submit button.. i want that when i select English Language and cick on submit then i redirect page English.php.

here is my code..  but it is not working....

```
<?php $lang=$_REQUEST['language'];  ?>
<form action="<?php echo $lang; ?>" method="Post">
<select name="language">
<option>select one</option>
<option>English</option>
<option>Hindi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: please sanitize user input.  See my post below.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a value in your option tag. However, it is not safe to let the user specify the script to run.  So you you should examine the values from the form in your PHP code and decide where to send the user.

```
<?php
    $lang=$_REQUEST['language'];

    switch ($lang) {
        case 'english':
            $page = 'english.php';
            break;
        case 'hindi':
            $page = 'hindi.php';
            break;    
        default:
            $page = null;
    }

    if ($page) {
        header("Location: ".$_POST['language']);
        exit;
    }

?>

<form method="post">
    <select name="language">
        <option value="">select one</option>
        <option value="english">English</option>
        <option value="hindi">Hindi</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you must have value defined for option

```
<select name="language">
   <option value="">select one</option>
   <option value="English.php">English</option>
   <option value="Hindi.php">Hindi</option>
</select>
```

above are `HTML` code now when form is posted redirect to selected option as below.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    header("Location: ".$_POST['language']);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: @user2748343 : filter your user's input or else you'll get hacked.

Answer (score 0):

or you can change the action of the form by jQuery, like:

```
$('select[name="language"]').change(function(){
   $('form').attr('action' , $(this).val())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find a more detailed approach

```
<script language="javascript">
     function goPage() {
          if (document.frm.language.value != '') {   
              document.frm.action = document.frm.language.value;
              document.frm.submit();   
          }
     }
</script>

<form name="frm" method="get">  
     <select name="language">
        <option value="">select one</option>
        <option value="English.php">English</option>
        <option value="Hindi.php">Hindi</option>
     </select>
     <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="javascript:goPage()" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

by using javascript

html code:

```
<select name="dropdpown" size="1" id="select-anchor">
   <option value="#link">foo</option>
   <option value="#link">bar</option>
</select>
```

script code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#select-anchor').change( function () {
            var targetPosition = $($(this).val()).offset().top;
            $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: targetPosition}, 'slow');
        });
    });
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kgzwE/1/)